# Postgres 13 pg_cron error on RDS that's hard to track down

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, pg-cron

## pg_cron jobs all fail with "role of....doesn't provide permission to schedule a job"

I'm working on getting `pg_partman` and `pg_cron` set up on RDS, but when my `pg_cron` jobs run, they return this error:

```
ERROR: The protected role of rds_super doesn't provide permission to schedule a job.
```

From the error text, it seems like I'm missing a simple permissions issue on something in the directory or resources holding `pg_cron`, but I can't find the source of the problem. And, it's possibly something else. A lot of Googling, hunting through sources, and trial-and-error hasn't lead me to any answers, and I'm hoping for help.

For background, this is Postgres 13.4 with `pg_cron` 1.3. These are the latest versions now available on RDS. My goal is to have `pg_cron` running jobs in various databases in this cluster, but I've reduced the problem example to the `cron` schema in `postgres`.

RDS defines a role named `rds_superuser` that doesn't have a login, which you can then grant to other users. We're using a custom role named `rds_super`, and have for years.

When you `create extension pg_cron` up on RDS, the install is into the `postgres` database by default, and it creates a new schema named `cron`. That's all fine. As a "hello world" version of the problem, here's a simple table and task to insert the current time every minute into a text field.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS cron.foo;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cron.foo (
    bar text
);

GRANT INSERT ON TABLE cron.foo TO rds_super;

INSERT INTO cron.foo VALUES (now()::text);

select * from cron.foo;

-- Run every minute
SELECT cron.schedule('postgres.populate.foo','*/1 * * * *',
$$INSERT INTO cron.foo VALUES (now()::text) $$);
```

The bare statement `INSERT INTO cron.foo VALUES (now()::text)` works fine, when connected directly as the `rds_super` user. But when it's executed through the `cron.job` defined above, the `cron.job_run_details` output has the right code, the expected user, but a failure result with this error:

```
ERROR: The protected role of rds_super doesn't provide permission to schedule a job.
```

Does this ring a bell for anyone? I've deleted, reinstalled, set permissions explicitly. No improvement.

## Public

This may be off, but I ran into a couple of things where it looked like I needed to provide access to `public`. I started in PG 9.4 or 9.5, couldn't get my head around securing public...and stripped all of the rights off it everywhere. Putting some back in may be needed here?

## Permissions checks

Here are the permissions checks that I could think of.

```
select grantor,
       grantee,
       table_schema,
       table_name,
       string_agg (privilege_type, ',' order by privilege_type) as grants

  from information_schema.role_table_grants
where table_catalog = 'postgres'
  and table_schema  = 'cron'
  and grantee       = 'rds_super'

group by 1,2,3,4

order by 1,2,3,4;
```

I gave the user all privileges on all of the tables, just to see if that cleared things up. No joy.

```
grantor          grantee     table_schema  table_name             grants
rds_super        rds_super   cron          foo                    DELETE,INSERT,REFERENCES,SELECT,TRIGGER,TRUNCATE,UPDATE
rds_super        rds_super   cron          job_run_details_plus   DELETE,INSERT,REFERENCES,SELECT,TRIGGER,TRUNCATE,UPDATE
rds_superuser    rds_super   cron          job                    DELETE,INSERT,REFERENCES,SELECT,TRIGGER,TRUNCATE,UPDATE
rds_superuser    rds_super   cron          job_run_details        DELETE,INSERT,REFERENCES,SELECT,TRIGGER,TRUNCATE,UPDATE
```

Nothing is obviously wrong with the schema rights:

```
select pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege('rds_super', 'cron', 'CREATE') AS create,
       pg_catalog.has_schema_privilege('rds_super', 'cron', 'USAGE')  AS usage;

create  usage
t       t
```

Likewise, nothing pops out when I check function execution rights:

```
   select proname, proargnames
     from pg_proc
    where has_function_privilege('rds_super',oid,'execute')
      and pronamespace::regnamespace::text = 'cron'
order by 1,2


proname                  proargnames
job_cache_invalidate
schedule                 {job_name,schedule,command}
schedule                 {schedule,command}
unschedule               {job_id}
unschedule               {job_name}
```

## Answer

I do not know if this is *the* answer, but it seems to have fixed my problem. *Spoiler*: Log in as the user the `pg_cron scheduler` background worker runs as.

I burned everything down and restarted, and then found that my jobs simply would not run. No error, no results. I checked the status of the background workers like this:

```
 select application_name,
        usename,
        backend_type,
        query,
        state,
        wait_event_type,
        age(now(),backend_start) as backend_start_age,
        age(now(),query_start)  as query_start_age,
        age(now(),state_change) state_change_age

  from pg_stat_activity
 where backend_type != 'client backend';
```

I noticed that the background worker had been running for over a day (it's loaded as a shared library), and seemed to be stuck. I rebooted the server, and redid everything logged in as `dbadmin`, instead of my custom user. That's the user name that the `pg_cron scheduler` process is running as, in this case. I don't remember if `dbadmin` is part of the package with RDS Postgres, or if it's something I added years back. There's nothing in the RDS `pg_cron` instructions about this, so maybe it's just me. I needed to set up its `search_path` and permissions a bit to get everything working the way I needed, but that's normal.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL_pg_cron.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least in my case, the answer is to run the jobs as the same user as the `pg_cron` background thread. I've posted more details to the end of the original question.